# group by and order by not working

Tags: php, mysqli, group-by

I am trying to get group by and order by to work together but no luck could someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
$get1_msg1 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from (select message_id, sender, receiver, message, read_status, time_sent from user_messages where receiver='".$_SESSION['userid']."' order by time_sent desc ) as temp group by sender order by time_sent desc ");
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You are using group by without aggregation function  .. could you explain me why?  and could you explain your goal

Comment: I am working on a simple message system. I want to list individual conversation to like message inbox but i do not want to list all the messages i just want to list the message received but only 1 per users instead of all messages. i am not sure if i explain it so that you can understand but i think its the best way.

Comment: I have  posted  a firts suggestion  let me know .. eventually update your post  add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: **ORDER BY** alters the order in which items are returned.

**GROUP BY** will aggregate records by the specified columns which allows you to perform aggregation functions on non-grouped columns (such as SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment  you  can try

```
    "select message_id, sender, receiver, message, read_status, time_sent 
    from user_messages  where message_id  in (
          select message_id 
          from user_messages  
          where (sender, time_sent) in ( 
                  select  sender, max(time_sent )
                  from user_messages 
                  where receiver='".$_SESSION['userid']."' 
                  group by sender
          )
    )
    and receiver='".$_SESSION['userid']."'";
```

Comment: No am sorry that listed all the message. this is one i want. if i have 3 users sending me message 1 of the 3 users send me 5 message another send me 3 and the other send me 1 i do not want to list all the message that the  users send i only need 1 message per from all users listed from recent users using desc. the query that i have listed about worked only problem is that it not order the result from recent to less recent.